# In hibernate when does Query fire and return ResultSet

Tags: hibernate

Can u please tell in hibernate when does Query fire and return ResultSet.
Tell from below example

```
Session session =sessionFactory.openSession();
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Client.class);
criteria.add(Restrictions.like("clientName","%"+search+"%"));
criteria.setMaxResults(10);
List list = criteria.list();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The query will be fired when it encounters `criteria.list()` in the code when using criteria and returns `List` of objects of class specified in `session.createCriteria('')`. Here it will be `Client` in your case.

You can find more options at [Criteria Documentation](http://www.dil.univ-mrs.fr/~massat/docs/hibernate-3.1/api/org/hibernate/Criteria.html)

Answer (score 0):

The line `List list = criteria.list();` returns the result as a `list`. This is a list of t he pojo objects associated with that table, i.e., `Client` in your code.